# Books for intermediate/advance students

Tags: reference-request, books

Most of the books about Buddhism I can find were made for Beginners, most are very good and touch the key points, easy to find and to buy.

The problem is that after a while I started to look for more advanced books, made for people that have already studied the key principles of the Dhamma and wanna take one step further, this is very hard to find!

Anyone can indicate a book about Buddhism (suttas, Abidhamma, techniques etc.) More suitable for advance students?

Comment: Have you read the sutta pitaka?

Comment: This sort of question is challenging in an SE environment since it is broad (Buddhism is huge), highly opinion based, and prone to answers in list format. If we can edit the question into something more concrete then it can be easily reopened.

Comment: Sutta pitaka is definitly a good advise and will give me a looooot of material :)

Comment: [Shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are off-topic on almost every SE site.

Answer (score 1):

What particular subject would you like to study? Just comment on this answer with a list of subjects you want to learn and I will put together a list for you and edit it in this comment.

Would you like to focus on a particular tradition within Theravada? (I'm assuming you're asking about Theravada because you are using Pali terms.)

Comment: Correct, Theravada, but currently Im reading a Mahayana book because it was the only (not for beginners) I could find :)

Comment: @konrad01 Ok, so would you like to focus on a particular tradition within Theravada such as the Ajahn Chah tradition, the Mahasi Sayadaw tradition, etc... And what kind of subject matter are you looking for? Medition? Wisdom teachings? There are a lot of intermediate and advanced Theravada books that you can get for free online so you'll have to be more specific on what you want.

Comment: Send me the url of your favourite ones :)

Comment: @konrad01 I don't want to clutter the page too much. I have a lot of free books in PDF form that I can give you. I have an email address bakmoon123@gmail.com and if you send an email there I will send you some if you like.

Comment: @konrad01 (and Bakmoon) Someone created a Chat room at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16470/dharma-books which would seems to be a good place to list and discuss dharma books!